# Python pathlib error while trying to access AWS lambda environment file during runtime

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, pathlib, python-os

I'm using a python 3.9 Lambda function with a layer-based module. The module requires an absolute path to a JSON file be provided which it uses to read/write data during runtime. The access occurs infrequently.

My thought was to create the json file in the lambda environment and I can access it fine using the path derived from:
`jsonPath = os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']+"/theFile.json"`

But the module is using pathlib and I cannot get past the following error:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "dd6f717c-1ede-4906-92cd-de52a441a416",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 35, in lambda_handler\n    tdSession = TDClient(client_id,redirect_uri,jsonPath)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/td/client.py\", line 116, in __init__\n    self.credentials_path = pathlib.Path(credentials_path)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py\", line 1082, in __new__\n    self = cls._from_parts(args, init=False)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py\", line 707, in _from_parts\n    drv, root, parts = self._parse_args(args)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py\", line 691, in _parse_args\n    a = os.fspath(a)\n"
  ]
}
```

It appears that some path args are getting lost, causing os.fspath() to throw an error. My primary guess is that it's due to providing a relative path.

Any ideas as to how I can make this work? Or is this a case where I need to use EFS?

Thanks!

### Update:

Tried this locally and got the same problem using both a relative path as well as an absolute path. Now guessing it might be due to how the path info is passed from the module to pathlib. Going to explore this.

## Update (Answered):

Found the issue and answered below.

Answer (score 0):

Package documentation was incorrect.

The class' init parameters described in the documentation failed to include an argument prior to the filePath I was having issues with, which meant that in the actual code, the filePath argument was not passed and remained it's default value of None.